# How to read folder structure and assign it to datastructure?

Tags: python

I'm only starting with python, and I'm trying to accomplish following:

I have a folder structure (simplified):

```
.
├── folder1
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── folder2
│   └── file3
└── folder3
    ├── file4
    ├── file5
    └── file6
```

I'd like to read filenames into some kind of a datastructure, that is able to distinguish which files are from the same folder. I've used glob in a one folder case, but is it possible to get for example following datastructure using glob?

```
files = [{file1, folder1}, {file2, folder1}, {file3, folder2}...]
```

Comment: [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)|[`os.scandir()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you'd rather get this kind of structure:

```
files = {folder1: [file1, file2], folder2: [file3], ...}
```

The following code will do the trick:

```
import os

rootDir = '.'
files = {}
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    files[dirName] = fileList
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that will work. What I need to do with the files is, that I list all combinations of 2 files, and for each pair I need to know if they're from the same folder.